# Python writing lines from list causes IndexError

Tags: python, list, line

I have been trying to think of a way to do the following:

A file is opened and read. The file contains the following

```
15;0
2;0
```

The lines are read, the first digit of the line replaces the second one and the first digit of the line is replaced by 0:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r+")

for line in f:
    if line != "\n":
        lineList = line.replace("\n", "").split(";")
        lineList[1] = lineList[0]
        lineList[0] = "0"
        dataLine = lineList[0] + ";" + lineList[1]
        f.write(dataLine)

f.close()
```

The issue occurs when writing the line to file. How can I write both lines at the end of the file and delete the first two lines? Thanks

Comment: show the traceback message please.

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range. The text file is populated with this http://imgur.com/xtddcJf

Comment: please edit your post to include the entire traceback message since I highly doubt that `f.write(..)` will raise an IndexError.

Comment: Please also reindent your code in the question properly, and do realize that you're mixing reads and writes in the text file which will not do what you'd expect, rather what you write into the file will overwrite the next characters in the line, and would push further that which you're going to read on the next iteration.

Comment: The entire trace back is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\coeh\Desktop\cw\players.py", line 344, in <module>
    start() #PROGRAM LAUNCHED
  File "C:\Users\coeh\Desktop\cw\players.py", line 52, in start
    goToNextRound()
  File "C:\Users\coeh\Desktop\cw\players.py", line 260, in goToNextRound
    lineList[6] = lineList[5]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: it is because you opened it in `r+` mode, are you sure you want to do that? it would be a lot easier to open it twice: once for reading and once for writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way to implement the solution (and probably a more logically correct way) is to first read the contents of the file within one context manager and after that to write the processed data to the same file within another context manager:

```
data = list()
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line != '\n':
            listLine = line.split(";")
            data.append("0;{}\n".format(listLine[0]))

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in data:
        f.write(line)
```

Also, you do not need the overhead of assigning different values to `listLine` list and then creating a data entry to write into your file. Just use straight ahead what you already have.

The downside of this method is memory usage - if your file will be bigger than your memory, you'll need another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code.

```
listLine = line.split(";")
lineList[1] = lineList[0]
lineList[0] = "0"
```

You set the variable listLine, and then you call lineList.

Comment: An error in simplifying the code fragment. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @iulian is a good one, but as he had warned - it requires enough memory to hold the data. If you expect large files and can accept temporarily using extra disk space (instead of RAM), you can write to a separate output file, write processed data, then replace the original one with it:

```
import shutil
import tempfile

with open("data.txt", "rU") as f_in:
    f_out = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    for line in f_in:
        if ";" in line:
            line = "0;{}\n".format(line.split(";", 1)[0])
        f_out.write(line)
    f_out.close()
    shutil.move(f_out.name, "data.txt")
```

You can't replace data in-place if you can't guarantee that new lines won't be longer than old ones. Shall this happen, you will encounter yourself in a situation where your write position is further than read one, and the file will be corrupt.

However, if you can be certain that no new line will be longer than an old one (e.g. there's definitely no `"1234;"` lines in source that would become `"0;1234"` after the transformation), you can do this as well:

```
with open("data.txt", "rb+") as f:
    write_offset = 0
    for line in f.readlines():
        line_len = new_len = len(line)
        if ";" in line:
            line = "0;{}\n".format(line.split(";", 1)[0])
            new_len = len(line)
            if new_len > line_len:
                # Bad things had just happened.
                raise RuntimeError("New line is longer than old one!"
                                   " File is now corrupt.")

        read_offset = f.tell()            # Remember the current position
        f.seek(write_offset)              # Seek to where we should write to
        f.write(line)
        write_offset += new_len
        f.seek(read_offset)               # Return to where we were

    # It could happen that new file is shorter.
    f.seek(write_offset)
    f.truncate()
```

This version does the updates in-place and doesn't have any extra memory or disk requirements.

(Note, `f.readlines()` has a buffer, so `f.tell()` results won't be individual line offsets - just in case you would want to use those for any reason. For our purposes we can safely ignore this here.)